# jQuery tab with multiple web forms

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to navigate multiple web pages using jQuery tab like below

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="General.aspx">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="Education.aspx">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="Employment.aspx">Employment</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is working fine, when I navigate through tab click. But, if any post back happens within the pages, they are popping out of the tab(with out tab). I tried using the tab in a Master Page, it is showing the tab properly in Master page, but showing the ul markup again in the child pages.

Since I have lot of condition checks in every page, I am trying with separate pages, rather than putting everything into one single page.

Currently I am using User Control as the menu, to navigate between these pages. I am just curious to try the same with jQuery tab. Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try adding the tabs in a master page ?

Comment: Did you try postback using `ajax`. Is that possible??

Comment: @Anand Yes I did, it is showing the tab properly in Master page, but showing the ul markup again in the child pages.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Sorry, I don't understand...

Comment: instead of refreshing the page for any purpose other than submitting you can just you ajax to post your page to `server` for any sort of validation or to retrieve value!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Nice idea, but I have so many post back controls within the pages, and also I am trying to use javascript/ajax at minimum level.

Comment: Then we need to think of other ways but that will really help you improve site performance!! :)

Comment: @Shanish, There are several ajax controls in asp.net like update panel, using your controls inside it will not trigger a post back, only controls inside the update panel will be refreshed. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Anand I want to keep the javascript usage at minimum level. I will check it. Thanks any how.

Comment: @shanish, no need to use javascript, update panel is also an asp control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Because Your web forms are targeting the same master page (this result in render the whole page including `html` and `head`... tags)! 
So, to solve this issue, you need to replace webforms by partial views (as of MVC) or simple user controls (as of WebForm) or webForm not having a master page, nor html tag

```
   <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="General.ascx">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="Education.ascx">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="Employment.ascx">Employment</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```